# Laravel blade getting distant relationship data

Tags: php, laravel

I have an album model which has many images, I can get this in the controller (and pass it to the view) like so:

```
$albums = Album::with('images')->get();
return view('welcome', ['albums' => $albums]);
```

Doing a var_dump on the data it seems to be working as expected:

```
images: 
(object) Illuminate\Database\EloquentCollection [Object ID: 377][Number of Properties: 1]
items:protected: 
(array) [Number of elements: 5]
0: 
(object) AppImage [Object ID: 382][Number of Properties: 24]
table:protected: (string) image
connection:protected: (null) NULL
primaryKey:protected: (string) id
keyType:protected: (string) int
incrementing: (boolean) true 
with:protected: 
(array) [Number of elements: 0]
perPage:protected: (integer) 15 
exists: (boolean) true 
wasRecentlyCreated: (boolean) false 
attributes:protected: 
(array) [Number of elements: 6]
id: (integer) 1 
filename: (string) vAIsX53hlkRUSkmohe0SyeEhEzkDTQnsQxrL3DKt.png
path: (string) images/20170322000000
album_id: (integer) 1 
created_at: (string) 2017-03-22 16:02:55
updated_at: (string) 2017-03-22 16:02:55
original:protected: 
(array) [Number of elements: 6]
id: (integer) 1 
filename: (string) vAIsX53hlkRUSkmohe0SyeEhEzkDTQnsQxrL3DKt.png
path: (string) images/20170322000000
album_id: (integer) 1 
created_at: (string) 2017-03-22 16:02:55
updated_at: (string) 2017-03-22 16:02:55
```

I loop over the albums and print the title out and that works just fine, but when trying to access the image objects in the album object I'm not getting any output:

```
                @foreach ($albums as $album)

                    {{ $album->name }} <br>
                    @foreach ($album->images() as $image)
                        {{ $image->filename }}
                    @endforeach

                @endforeach
```

`{{ $album->name }}` works as expected but I have no output for `{{ $image->filename }}` am I trying to access the image filename incorrectly?

Comment: It is an array inside. It should be `$image['filename']` I guess. Give it a try?

Comment: @Thamilan `$album->images()` is actually a query builder object inside. Once they change it to `$album->images` it will be a Model instance inside. Because models implement the ArrayAccess interface attributes can be accessed either with `$image->filename` OR `$image['filename']`. Both are valid and correct.

Answer (score 3):

When you call the relationship as a method it returns a query builder instance. You need to change it to a property call to get the collection of images.

So change

```
@foreach ($album->images() as $image)
```

to

```
@foreach ($album->images as $image)
```